# AJAX Submit to PHP still loading page after preventDefault()

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a webpage that I am using .ajax to send variables to a php script. The php page is loading into the browser as if I was navigating to it. The script is loading the data correctly, so my issue is stopping the navigation and keeping the user on the original page. The code for my form is here:

```
echo "<form method='post' action='addTask.php' id='myform'>\n";
echo "<input name='addtask' id='addtask' maxlength='64'/><br/>\n";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Add Task'/>\n";
echo "</form>\n";
```

The code for my jquery is here:

```
    $(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addTask.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: alert("Success")
            });
        });
    });
```

I have tried: e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropagation() and return false. Any help is appreciated.

```
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addtask.php",
            data: { }
        })
        .done(function() {
            alert( "success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        });
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addTask.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function(){alert("Success")}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to get rid of the `submit` call, this is what triggers the redirect behavior

Comment: the alert needs to be in a function... and I usually use `e.preventDefault();`.  not sure if there is a difference.

Comment: e.stopPropagation() only stops the event from propagating, it prevents nothing ?

Comment: change success to `success: function(){ alert("success"); }`

Comment: ^^^ What he said, and using done() would be even better.

Comment: e.preventDefault should have worked. Can you show an example of how you used e.preventDefault?

Comment: Seems to work fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/t5jGF/

Comment: Edit: added to main question

Comment: Did you at any point open the console (F12) to see if there where any errors ?

Comment: Your code works, the problem must be elsewhere. Did you include jQuery? Is the form dynamically added to the page?

Comment: And your comment just helped me figure it out. I had <script src='jquery.js'>
// all the code
</script>
it worked. Thank you!

once i put the <script src='jquery.jg></script>
<script>
//code
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success preventing the form submission by returning false after the ajax call.

```
$(function () {
    $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addTask.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: alert("Success")
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5c3n2/

### Edit:

The code above demonstrates how `return false` prevents form submission. However, as mentioned by gloomy.penguin, `success` should be a function. Also, since the call will never succeed on jsFiddle, I added `complete`.

```
$(function () {
    $('#myform').submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'addTask.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function() {alert("Success");},
            complete: function() {alert("Completed");}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5c3n2/2/

Comment: And this is different how exactly ?

Comment: How is it different from the OP's code? I added `return false` after the ajax call.

Comment: It's still loading addTask.php on the server, even with return false. I see it's working in jsfiddle but my live version isn't working properly still. Does it have to do with the action tag on the form?

Comment: he likely just picked a random answer, the problem was he never actually included his javascript in a place where it would get executed.

Comment: The action attribute shouldn't matter if you're preventing the default form submission. But you also don't need it in your form tag because it's already in your ajax call.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for the update. I wasn't following the comments on the actual question.

Answer (score -1):

try to prevent default on the submit button:

```
$('input#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //submit your form
});
```

Comment: Read the question, it says the OP already tried that? Or, at least on the form submit, which is a much better idea than this ?

Comment: what? this is a completely different function````` this is selecting the submit button``

Comment: This is different from what he tried, he also removed the submit call

Comment: I'd consider going from a submit handler to a click handler a downgrade in functionality, and it will cause his submit handler to stop working without moving all of his submit handler code into this event handler, at which point i suspect he'd have the same problem because the real problem is elsewhere.